# ASP.NET code execution halts after certain time on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a long running task on my application which  takes approximately 4/5 hours to complete. That task retrieves data from a CUBE data server for hundreds of combinations by iterating through loop.

It works fine while I run it from my local Visual Studio 2015 but when I deploy it on our application server this process automatically halts after 25/30 minutes. As I monitor from the CUBE server I can see that after 25/30 mins no data call receives there.

I had tried in web.config the following and set session timeout to 20 hours from  IIS but nothing works as the data calls halts after certain  time and doesn't fully completes.

> executionTimeout="86400"

The code has given below-

> Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunManufacturerModuleCache(),
>   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

Where **RunManufacturerModuleCache()** method has a for loop of 1000 iterations and each iteration fetches data from a CUBE server.

Is there any settings that can extend execution time in IIS that I'm missing or there is no way to run an execution process greater than 25/30 minutes in IIS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IIS has an application pool idle-timeout (default is 20 minutes). Just go to application pools in IIS, right click your application pool and "Advanced Settings". You will see there's a setting called "Idle time-out (minutes)". Set it to 0 if you don't want your app pool to automatically shutdown when no requests are received for a long time period.

Alternatively, you can keep sending a request to the application home page (or any simple page) every few minutes to keep the app pool awake.

Ps.
As far as best practices go, you should not put long running tasks inside request processing pipeline. Rather, you should create a separate service (Windows Service, Azure WebJob etc..) to execute long running tasks but that's a separte discussion.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution i.e. setting 0 to Idle time-out (minutes) works for me!